# NameError: name 'traingenerator' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

can you please help solving the error below?

```
data_gen = trainGenerator(3,PATH,'images','GT',data_gen_args, save_to_dir = None)
```

> ```
> **NameError**                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-11-746d90bd9664> in <module>()
>       1 
> ----> 2 data_gen = traingenerator(3,PATH,'images','GT',data_gen_args, save_to_dir = None)
>
> NameError: name 'traingenerator' is not defined
> ```

Comment: You just don't have any traingenerator function apparently... check if the function is written BEFORE the code that raises this error if the function is appearing below the main code that can cause this issue

Comment: No i don't. Can you please tell me how to do it? I'm new at coding.

Comment: post a part or all of your code that would be easier for everyone. or at least the part of the code that is failing and the functions involved

Comment: You most likely forgot an import. BTW, the code you posted did not generate that error. Please make sure you post the correct code. Remember Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

here is the part of code:

```
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.3,
                 rescale=1./255,
                width_shift_range=0.2,
                height_shift_range=0.2,
                shear_range=0.1,
                zoom_range=[0.7,1],
                horizontal_flip=True,
                vertical_flip=True,
                fill_mode='nearest')
```

PATH='C:/Users/CSM/Desktop/ressources/train/GT/
import os
if not os.path.exists(PATH+'aug'):
os.makedirs(PATH+'aug')

if not os.path.exists(PATH+'pred'):
os.makedirs(PATH+'pred')
data_gen = trainGenerator(3,PATH,'images','GT',data_gen_args, save_to_dir = None)